# C# SafeGetInt for SqlDataReader performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, optimization

I am reading a lot of data manually from a `SqlDataReader` in loops. I have created extension methods to not crash whenever there is incorrect data or when I am trying to read from columns the actual SQL statement is missing.

My extension method looks like this:

```
public static int SafeGetInt(this SqlDataReader reader, string field)
{
    try
    {
        int colIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(field);

        if (!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
            return reader.GetInt32(colIndex);

        return 0;
    }
    catch
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The purpose is to be able to do:

```
myObject.myProperty = reader.SafeGetInt("MyColumn");
```

My question: is there any more sophisticated way of doing this? My main concern is that because this particular method is running thousands of times, and actually quite often throwing an exception. I read that throwing exceptions can actually slow down your application. I have similar extension methods for strings, double and booleans.

Comment: Have you measured a performance problem?

Comment: If the exception is being thrown because there is no column with the name `field` then it may be an idea to record the invalid column name the first time it occurs and check that a column name is not invalid each time. You will need to do some testing to determine whether it is worth spending the extra time doing the checks to save the time the exceptions cost.

Comment: I would suggest using Dapper instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: So, you have no way of actually storing `0`s in your database? Or no way to distinguish between a failed read and such values? An interesting definition of "safe". In general, code which *hides* errors and causes you to fall over later due to the error being hidden are *harder* to diagnose than code that immediately errors when reality doesn't match expectations.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! @MitchWheat I have not any data on this, but I read that throwing exceptions is costly with respect to performance, is that incorrect?

Comment: Probably start religious war, but, it's not the cost of throwing exceptions, it's using exceptions for flow control that should be avoided (IMO). That Said, using Dapper will save you a lot of work.

Comment: I agree, using exception for controlling the flow is exactly what my question is about. How can I refactor the method above without using the exception to control the flow. I understand Dapper is good but don't find reasons enough to refactor my code for it.